# Performance of clock_gettime() on numa

Tags: linux, performance, networking, time, profiling

How does clock_gettime runs on NUMA?

I have a packet processing code on "Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 v2 @ 2.60GHz" which has two 8 core CPUs. It uses clock_gettime() to timestamp every received packet.

If I run it on any core on CPU 0 using (numactl --physcpubind), it can process 6 Million packet per second but if I just comment clock_gettime() it can run 14Mpps. 
I don't see this effect when I run the program on cores of CPU 1 and it can process 14Mpps with or without clock_gettime.

Details:

- I use clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts); where ts is a local variable
- Ubuntu 14.04.1 , 3.13.0-35-generic
- gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2
- I compile using -g -O2 -lrt -lpthread
- One receive queue for NIC. This pattern happens regardless of the core affinity of NIC queue.
- CPU flags are: fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm ida arat xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms
- Hyperthreading is disabled
- NIC: X520-T2 10G link

Comment: What about compiling using "-O3 -lrt -lpthread" flags?

Comment: Same result with -O3

Comment: You can write short test just with ten `clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);` and run strace over it to check is there system calls inside it. Man http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html lists several other clock, and CLOCK_REALTIME_COARSE or CLOCK_MONOTONIC_COARSE  may have less overhead - http://lwn.net/Articles/342018/. On NUMA all high-precision clocks uses synchronized TSC (cpu clock counter), and sometimes it not exactly synchronized between sockets (either ~100-300 tick offsets or event periodic in-kernel resync and different rates)